# What's the advantage of using jQuery Mobile's fancy page transition system?

Tags: forms, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to put a fairly simple app together fairly quickly, and I'm new to jQuery Mobile, so I'm faced with a design decision that I need some input on.

Some of my pages use forms to pass data via GET to the next page. Now that I'm revising the app with jQuery Mobile, I find that I need to apply 'data-ajax="false"' to each of them in order to pass the data to the page the old-fashioned way. This stops the next page from being loaded via ajax.

I'm content with this, but I'm aware of the alternative-- completely revising my present model to accomodate jQuery Mobile's ajax system. I'm reluctant to do this because it would take more of my time to figure out and more of my time to re-implement.

So the question is this: what would be the advantage in re-writing my app to operate as a single DOM with many pages loaded via ajax, using jQuery Mobile's data passing system? Why should I care or bother?

(Can you tell I barely understand how their forms system works to begin with?)

Answer (score 3):

One advantage of the "JQM way" is that you are never leaving the first page.

Think of it like this:
Your first page loaded will be your "anchor page" that all other pages will be added to/removed from. Only when you go to a link with data-rel="external" or data-ajax="false", the new page loaded will be your next anchor.

JQM needs to do this to enable transitions (basically it's loading the new page into the existing DOM, drops it "next" to the current page and then slides it over). If you go to a new page altogether without AJAX, there is no way to have animations.

For your example this could mean, no need to pass data along from page to page, because you when going from page to page in JQM, ... you are never really leaving the first page.

I'm usually attaching an object to $('html') or $(document), which contains any stuff I need on subsequent pages.

You don't even need to submit anything, just bind to a [JQM event](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) like

```
  pagebeforehide
```

which will be fired before you are leaving a certain page. In the function handler fill your  object with the form values and on the last form page before submit, just populate hidden inputs with the stored form values from previous pages on

```
 pagebeforeshow
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Once again nice answer frequent.